# Como posso executar essa query com Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, query, count

Como eu executaria a seguinte *query* no Laravel 5:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(`anuncios`.`cat-id`)
FROM `anuncios` WHERE `anuncios`.`cat-id`=`categoria`.`cat-id`)
AS `cat-total`
FROM `categoria`
ORDER BY `cat-nome` ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse jeito é com Inner Join.
Mas se quiser algo mais organizado mesmo, faça o que o Wallace postou.

```
<?php
    $anuncios = Categoria::orderBy('cat-nome')
                ->join('anuncios', 'anuncios.cat-id', '=', 'categoria.cat-id')
                ->selectRaw('*, count(anuncions.cat-id) as cat-total')
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que criar os models referentes as tabelas.

```
class Anuncio
{
     protected $table = 'anuncios';
}


class Categoria
{
      protected $table = 'categorias';
}
```

Depois crie o relacionamento em `Anuncio` para `categorias`.

```
public function categorias()
{
     return $this->hasMany('Categoria', 'cat-id', 'cat-id');
}
```

E por fim, você não precisa do `count` no `SELECT`, mas simplesmente pode usar um recurso presente no `Collection` do `Laravel`.

```
$anuncios = Anuncio::with('categorias')->get();
```

Quando estiver usando o `foreach`, basta fazer:

```
foreach($anuncios as $anuncio)
{
      echo $anuncio->categorias->count();
}
```

Pode parecer mais complexo, mas eu preferiria utilizar a forma com que o `Laravel` abstrai cada tabela, para tornar mais fácil a reutilização dos dados do banco.